# How to open folders in VSCode via Terminal in full screen?

Tags: visual-studio-code

When I open a folder in vscode via iTerm2 the vscode is not display in full screen. How to make it default to in full screen?

Comment: Try https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/22762

Comment: @Gosha_Fighten I didn't use tmux.